# listview items are not shown

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I have a listview in C# , I simply add this to it, **listView1.Items.Add("asdasdasd");** , but the only thing shown is a listview without any item ( but when I debug it, it is shown that listview HAS an item)

I have no idea why it is not shown.

Comment: that can't be all the code you have.. please show all relevant code..

Comment: _but the only thing shown is a listview without any item_ Where do you see it? It doesn't in debug mode anyway?

Comment: Is your control disabled? Did you call .BeginUpdate() and aren't calling .EndUpdate() ?

Comment: thanks guys, I copied another listview that I knew it worked right, and the problem is solved, but still I dont know what the problem was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your `ListView` has no columns set or the width of first column is set to zero. Try adding a column to the list (you can do it via property browser).

Comment: mmm, I had another listview, it worked right, but I didnt set column to that either

Comment: well, does it have columns or not? what are the widths? what is the view mode? Your question is very scarce on information.

Comment: I know Zdeslav, but I copied from that listview and it works fine now, thanks for your comment